# How can I resize all photos to the same size?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:[link](http://bagelhousecafe.ch/)

but i have the following problem:[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PXp1.jpg)

What I want to do is:

**1.** the two images must have a width of `33.3333%` , but the middle image must
  remain as it is

another of my problems is when I resize the browser,the middle image is much higher.

**CSS**

```
.inline-block{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left-img,.right-img{
  width: 33.3333%;
}
.left-img{
  background: url("/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-01.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
.ctr-img{
  background: url("/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-02.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
.right-img{
  background: url("/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-03.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-img inline-block">
   <img src="/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-01.png" alt="Mountain View" style="visibility: hidden;">    
</div>

<div class="ctr-img inline-block">
   <img src="/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-02.png" alt="Mountain View" style="visibility: hidden;">   
</div>

<div class="right-img inline-block">
   <img src="/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-03.png" alt="Mountain View" style="visibility: hidden;">       
</div>
```

Comment: `33.3333%` means `100 / 3` but it seems you are not setting this width for the middle image hence the layout looks off , you could try adding the width to the middle image as well or you could try `absolute` positions

Answer (score 0):

This will not be possible with just HTML / CSS. You will have to use Javascript. For your layout, I would suggest taking a look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: masonry only can it?
If you can please help me with a quick example using masonry jsdfidle my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you're trying to make all the three images of the same size, and this isn't happening when you're resizing the browser. 
Well that, I think, is because you're specifying the width of left and the right images as 33% of screen and you're not setting the width of middle image. Try adding the ctr-image class also to that CSS block. i.e.,

```
.left-img,.ctr-img,.right-img{
    width: 33.3333%;
}
```

instead of just

```
.left-img,.right-img{
    width: 33.3333%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a { max-width: 100%; } in your main.css file, remove it, and add {width: 100%}...

```
img {
    border: 0;
    max-width: 100%; /* Remove this line */
    width: 100%; /* Add this line */
    height: auto;
}
```

Then, You must make all 3 images in same height! Resize your images to same height... for example if your minimum height is 177px (first image), the second image must resize to (184x177) and the last image must be (235x177).

Finally, add { width: 33%; } for the center image-div

```
.ctr-img {
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: It is good but can you help me to make and images until end?
I want the image to be slightly smaller center.

Answer (score 0):

```
    click here to website 

    https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/resize-images-css/

    you get an idea 





   use like that:
    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
      img.ri { max-width: 90%; }
    }

    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
      img.ri { max-height: 90%; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use framework with grid system (Bootstrap par exemple). With three images, you need to set .col-md-4, .col-sm-4, .col-xs-4 to each image and then you have a perfect display.

To make all three images have the same height, if u want, u can fix the height. If not, the following solution works well:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 56.25% 0;
}

.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Change 56.25% to the value that is best for you and then you will have what you want.

This is an exemple with your images: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/lampt2509/pen/yJeZmJ)